# spring-amqp unable to use custom MessagingMessageListenerAdapter in SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory

Tags: spring-amqp

In spring-amqp 2.0.3.RELEASE module it's no possible to use custom MessagingMessageListenerAdapter in SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.

Even thought registration own bean we stuck at highest one, where last object instance just hard created thought "new MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint" at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#processAmqpListener.

Maybe spring developers could add some producer registration to SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory like "smlcf.setMessageListenerAdapterCreator"

Comment: Would you mind to share with us a reason why do you need a *custom* `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`? Maybe there are some other ways to customize a use case...

Comment: I need to add retry functionality for replyto sending Message function in messageListenerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking can be done via a `RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` extension:

```
@Bean(name = RabbitListenerConfigUtils.RABBIT_LISTENER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
static RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor myRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {

    return new RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {

         @Override
         protected void processListener(MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint, RabbitListener rabbitListener, Object bean,
            Object adminTarget, String beanName) {

                  super.processListener(new MyMethodRabbitListenerEndpoint(), rabbitListener, proxy, adminTarget, beanName);
         }
    };
}
```

But what you are saying about retry for the reply really makes sense and we definitely should consider to let to inject a `RabbitTemplate` into the `RabbitListenerContainerFactory`.

Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter.

Comment: Thank you, for the hint, but while creating MessagingMessageListenerAdapter debug shows that MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint creates at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#processAmqpListener method, and there is not comfortable to override it, because in this method private methods are used

Comment: Furthermore, yours solutions makes me to support all presets which were made with endpoint before calling proccessListener.

Comment: To be honest there is not too much code in the `processAmqpListener()` method: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java. That’s why I suggest just to ignore its logic and override the method it calls

Comment: For now it's not too much, but if we will override it, all responsibility will lay on us, and after each new release we will need to ch check changes in those method.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a story for adding retry functionality for ReplyTo https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-825